# Convert String to Long using BufferReader

Tags: long-integer, primitive-types

I'm trying to convert my input read Strings to long (Long). I've tried the `valueof()` and `Long.Parslong(String s)` but no luck. Im not sure what is going on. I can certainly print the String but cannot convert to Long ):

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] sheet = line.split(cvsSplitBy);    //comma as separator
                if(isNumeric(sheet[3])){                    //parse into integer, only if first col is num 
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(sheet[0]);
                    int pop = Integer.parseInt(sheet[3]); 
                    System.out.println(sheet[4]);
                    System.out.println(sheet[4].getClass().getName()); 
                    Long lon  = Long.valueOf(sheet[4]); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

......skip

The Error is the usual **NumberFormatException**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34.95"
```

Any ideas? Thanks Aj

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the description of the exception.

```
For input string: "34.95"
```

It has a Decimal value, which can't convert into a Long. You could either use `Double.valueOf("34.95")` or do a validation for non integer values.

Comment: Thanks dude. Java primitive types 101.

Comment: Happy that I could help. Please accept the answer if you think this is correct.

Comment: im new. I either cant find it or dont have enough points. I cant upvote either ):

Comment: oh that's ok. I upvoted your question just to get some points. :)